# PHP Object creation, Factory Method and Dependency Injection

Tags: php, dependency-injection, factory-method

I'm looking forward for a nice pattern to create objects that are bound to a database. I'm going to illustrate my thoughts with a simple example: the creation of a user.

First: Factory method to Create/Load a user. User configuration is done in the new created instance.

```
$user = User::Create($db); // Flag the instance to create an user when save() is called
$user->setUsername('...'); 
$user->set...; 
$user->save(); // Will insert a new user into the database.

...
$user = User::Load($db, id); // Load an user from the database. Flag object to update.
$user->setUsername('...'); // Change username.
$user->save(); // Update existing object instead of inserting a new one.
```

Second: Factory method to create immediatly a new user.

```
User::Create($db, $username, $password, ...); // Create and insert a new user.
...
$user = User::Load($db, 1);
$user->setUsername("..."); // Change username.
$user->save(); // Save only updates a user, no flag needed because an user is entirelly created by User::Create().
```

Third: Using a factory class with static factory methods.

```
Factory::newUser($db, $username, $password, ...); // May contain many other types of objects.
```

And i can do always something like this:

```
$factory = new Factory($db);
$user = $factory->newUser($username, $password, ...);
```

Another thing is, should i create a singleton that provides an handle to a database that will be used on the application to create objects (without hardcoding the handle inside objects) ?

Example:

```
class DB {
    public static function handle() { /* Do a lazy connection to a database once. */ }
}

...
$user = User::Create(DB::handle(), ...);
```

So, my real question is, what's the best pattern? I know that this might be too relative, but i need some hints, and of course, i want to leave the dependencies outside, not hardcoded inside objects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem comes from "model layer" you should look for database patterns, such as:

- [Data Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern)
- [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

Comment: Yea this is great, but i need something simpler because this is for an assignment at school (actually the first in php) and i'm looking for simple, yet consistent way of creating objects connected to a database. Thanks for your tip.